# I noticed that AWS CodePipeline creates its S3 folder that has block all public access set to off

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I noticed that AWS CodePipeline creates its S3 folder that has block all public access set to off.
I assume that means anyone can see the code in this folder that is deployed using this pipeline?

If true then that is bad!!!!
How can I make it private by default so only my CodePipline can see it?

Comment: I did just manually set this head S3 CodePipline folder to private and ran another build through my CodePipeline. The pipeline worked fine. I wonder why AWS would not set this folder to block all public access by default when CodePipeline creates it when you set up the pipeline.

Comment: The "block public access" flag in S3 is relatively new, however as @shariqmaws says, your objects are not public by default. I'll submit a feature request to set the block public access flag by default as an extra precaution.

Answer (score 3):

The artifact bucket created by CodePipeline is not public. On the S3 console, you can confirm it says "Objects can be public" which translates to: [1]

> The bucket is not public, but anyone with the appropriate permissions
>   can grant public access to objects

This can also be confirmed via the ACL tab under the bucket details in S3 console. Also the default Bucket policy restricts unencrypted objects and insecure connections.

This means that while bucket is not Public, individual objects can be Public with appropriate ACL.

'Block all public access' is a higher-level restrictive setting to block public access to all of your objects at the bucket or the account level.

This means that Public ACL objects in the bucket will also be blocked due to this overarching setting.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/s3-user-guide.pdf